# Problem with loading GNU Go mode

Tags: init-file

I have installed GNU Go 3.8 and am trying to use it in emacs. I have downloaded `gnugo.el` from [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/gnugo.el) and have copied `gnugo-big-xmps.el` from my `gnugo-3.8/interface` directory, putting both in my `.emacs.d`. I have the following two lines in my `init.el`:

```
(autoload 'gnugo "gnugo" "GNU GO" t)
(autoload 'gnugo-xpms "gnugo-big-xpms" "GNU GO" t)
```

I can use `M-x gnugo`, and am prompted for `GNU Go options:`, but when I press `RET`, I get the error `Searching for program: no such file or directory, gnugo`. I don't think that this is a problem with my installation of GNU Go, since it works fine from the command line. Can anyone help?

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 on OS X El Capitan, 10.11.3.

Comment: Check the value of `M-h v exec-path`, and see if `gnugo` is in one of the locations listed in there. If it's not, simply add the directory where `gnugo` lives to this list. (eg. `(push (shell-command-to-string "dirname $(which gnugo)") exec-path)`.

Comment: Tried doing this with `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/usr/local/bin")))` and `(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("~/Downloads/gnugo-3.8")))`, and now get the error message `Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, gnugo` before even getting the prompt for `GNU Go options:`

Comment: Well, this means that the file with the Emacs Lisp code for `gnugo` isn't on the `load-path`. I don't quite understand how would the `utoload` work before, but it seems like you need to put the Emacs Lisp sources for the game somewhere on the `load-path` (or again, add the directory with the sources to the `load-path`). It was probably better to keep the `gnugo.el` where it was and instead add its parent directory to `load-path`.

Comment: Added the folder containing `gnugo` to the `load-path`, am now getting the original problem. Relevant section in my `init.el`: 
`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/gnugo-3.8/interface")`
`(autoload 'gnugo "~/.emacs.d/gnugo-3.8/interface/gnugo.el" "GNU GO" t)`
`(autoload 'gnugo-xpms "~/.emacs.d/gnugo-3.8/interface/gnugo-big-xpms.el" "GNU GO" t)`

Comment: Try `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and once you get this error, look at the backtrace (the buffer will pop-up showing the list of function calls from the last to the first). `RET` on a function name in this buffer will open the function's definition, there you'll be able to see what the function was doing when it received the error (i.e. where it was trying to look for `gnugo`).

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

- Add `gnugo-3.8/interface` to my `.emacs.d`
- Add this directory to **both** the `load-path` and the `exec-path`

My problem was that the directory I added to the `exec-path` contained directories that contained `gnugo`, rather than containing `gnugo` directly.